# xubuntu black screen with mouse cursor

Tags: xubuntu

It`s a Dell Latitude E4310 with Xubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Before was everything all right, than I changed the HDD, with a new SSD, fresh install. this was about a half year ago, or maybe more.

Now, I want to revert to the old, original HDD, because I got a new laptop to use the SSD with, I restored the original HDD to the dell, which was ok before, but now is not.

After the system starts up I have a black screen with only the mouse cursor, and if I press alt-F2 the application finder shows up, wit the applications as well, except some like the terminal emulator. All the apps seems to work fine, I just have no desktop, no panels, no rigt-click.

If I log out, and log in again, the desktop background appears, but nothing else.

I`m attaching some photos below:

[image: This is the first screen]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt install xfce4 solved the problem, but it`s strange how does disappeared

Answer (score -1):

Try

- `sudo apt purge xubuntu-desktop xdm && sudo apt purge *xfce* && sudo apt autoremove'

  - `sudo apt clean`
  - `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop lightdm`

Alternatively you could create new user and test if it looks differently for it.